# How do I iterate through the points on a straight line?

Tags: java

Is there a way to iterate through all the points on a line in java 2D?

I've looked through the class documentation and can't see anything that does it built in. If not, would it be better to extend the class and write my own method which calculates the equation of the line and then goes through each point? (Would this actually work as the theoretical equation of a line and the pixels that it actually draws in seem to be slightly different)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? In theory, a line has an uncountable infinity of points (and what is drawn on the screen is always an approximation). How would you handle zooming of that line?

Comment: I am trying to make a sprite move along a sloping ramp which is a line. So the sprite coordinates follow that of the line as it moves up or down. I thought the best way to do that was to iterate each point or several and then add them onto the sprite coordinates. Maybe that was silly but I couldn't think of a better solution.

Comment: Looking at the [Line2D documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#getPathIterator(java.awt.geom.AffineTransform)) there appears to be an iterator  .  I've never used Java 2D, but it looks like that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For something moving on a line with a constant velocity, its coordinates are an affine function of time:

```
x(t) = vx*t + x0
y(t) = vy*t + y0
```

where `(vx,vy)`  is the constant velocity (or speed) vector and `(x0,y0)` the origin position (at time 0).

I suggest reading some basic introductory course on [kinematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematic_equation#Equations_of_uniformly_accelerated_motion)

So you probably don't want to "iterate on the line" but simply to move something on the screen, that is to compute its position at every time quantum.

<sup>(I've learned such equations at high-school, in France)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to do something along the lines of a bounding box. Essentially, you should have an imaginary box around your sprite. Then just check when the bounding box intersects with the line. When it does, you move your sprite in the opposite direction.

[This question on Game Development Stack Exchange should help.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7890/2d-object-aligned-bounding-box-intersection-test)